# Interpretation of the p-value

Tags: probability, statistics, physics, hypothesis-testing

I would like to be sure about the correct interpretation of the p-value considering the $\chi^2$ test for a fit.

I know that the null-hypotesis must be accept or refuse based on whether the p-value is greater or less than the significance level. 
However it is correct to say that it is the probability that if the experiment were performed again then you would get a bigger $\chi^2$ and then a fit tha less 
corresponds the data. 
I would like to be sure about the practical interpretation of this parameter.

Comment: Best to view P-val just as a way to judge whether to Reject hull hypothesis. It is possible to give an interpretation of P val that keeps statisticians, probabilists, and philosophers all happy. But then it takes a lecture to get the avg experimenter not to misinterpret the statement. Some editors of psych journals have banned use of P-val because of abuses of iit eadi to non-reproducibile expts. Overkill, but maybe understandable.// Schopenhauer: "_Philosophy_ is the systematic abuse of a terminology established just for that purpose." (Maybe P-value fits that too.)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

You only need to add, that the $p$-value is the probability of getting a larger $\chi^2$ than $\chi_{sample}^2$ **under the assumption that $H_0$ is true**:

$$p = P(\chi^2 > \chi_{sample}^2 \, | H_0)$$